# Deep links in native iOS app redirect user to change my password page in safari

Tags: single-sign-on

I am working on native iOS app which has deep links for account and case detail page. When i click in that link it opens the correct page in iPad safari browser using sso, this works fine in QA.

In prod environment, the same link opens change my password security question screen.

https://abc.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00DG0000000jQYr!AQUAQAXrT0q9YK6YyiMkInMyXq7D8hlW6veyjpgVh_CDa8oRWKovP9pYO_Ps1q487VVQy5iBv9QvhNnDVnaKtYPx21dRI3Lh&retURL=https://abc.my.salesforce.com/Case or account id

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm facing the same issue.